# jquery expand / collapsible list not working

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, html-lists

I am trying to set up an expandable / collapsible list of content on a page and for some dumb reason it is not working.

This is all of the relevant javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://digitaldemo.net/forbes/wp-content/themes/forbes/js/jquery.expander.js"></script>
<script>
$('ul.expander li').expander({
  slicePoint: 50,
  widow: 2,
  expandEffect: 'show',
  userCollapseText: '[^]'
});
</script>
```

and the list code:

```
<ul class="expander">
<li>Intro text <span class="read-more"><a href="#">[more link]</a></span><span class="details">and full text goes here</span></li>
</ul>
```

The site is a WP site however I am not using a plugin for this. I am probably missing something stupid simple, as I am in the midst of an all-nighter. Any input would be helpful.

Here is the page: http://digitaldemo.net/forbes/?page_id=34

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<script>
$('ul.expander li').expander({
  slicePoint: 50,
  widow: 2,
  expandEffect: 'show',
  userCollapseText: '[^]'
});
</script>
```

By

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('ul.expander li').expander({
    slicePoint: 50,
    widow: 2,
    expandEffect: 'show',
    userCollapseText: '[^]'
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are missing is not loading the script when doc get ready.
simpley do like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.expander li').expander({
  slicePoint: 50,
  widow: 2,
  expandEffect: 'show',
  userCollapseText: '[^]'
});
});
</script>
```